# Intl not defined error , add intl support to V8

Tags: internationalization, v8, dayjs

I am executing javascript using V8 in my project and i am getting this error:

```
Stack: ReferenceError: Intl is not defined
    at getDateTimeFormat (dayjs@1.11.0/plugin/timezone/index.js:24:5)
    at makeFormatParts (dayjs@1.11.0/plugin/timezone/index.js:50:15)
    at tzOffset (dayjs@1.11.0/plugin/timezone/index.js:55:24)
    at Function.d.tz (dayjs@1.11.0/plugin/timezone/index.js:160:26)
```

i compiled V8 from source code . I used V8 11.6 version (the latest stable one for macOs). Here is the args.gn file

```
dcheck_always_on = false
is_debug = false
target_cpu = "arm64"
v8_target_cpu = "arm64"
v8_monolithic = true
v8_static_library = true
use_libfuzzer = false
v8_enable_test_features = ""
symbol_level = 0
is_component_build = false
use_sysroot = false
use_glib = false
use_custom_libcxx = false
use_custom_libcxx_for_host = false
v8_enable_i18n_support = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false
```

i generated the v8lib_monolith.a and copied in my project v8 folder. Am i missing something here to have i18n support?

Comment: @273K i have wrapper c++ files where i am calling v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(lib_path) , the js interacts with c++ in the project still facing the error

Answer (score 1):

When I follow the official instructions at [v8.dev/docs/embed](https://v8.dev/docs/embed), I get a working `Intl` object.

Perhaps you've missed one of the ICU-related steps? The instructions tell you to copy `icudtl.dat` into the directory where your binary is. And the sample code shows how to call `v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);` to initialize ICU.

It's probably easiest to start with the official "hello world" example along with its build instructions, and then incrementally modify things to your needs.

---

(<s>Note: there is currently one detail missing from the official docs: you need to either</s>

- add `-DV8_ENABLE_SANDBOX` to the compilation command for your own code,
- ***or*** add `v8_enable_sandbox = false` to V8's compilation args

In other words, either both V8 and your code need to be compiled with sandbox support, or both without.
**Update**: The official documentation has been updated to include this.)