# Intl not defined in V8 8.8

Tags: v8, intl, embedded-v8

I build v8 as a static monolithic library for my macOS x86_64 system (for a javascript runtime project). The V8 version i used is 8.8.278.17.
Followed the steps from https://v8.dev/docs/i18n
Still when i try to execute a javascript code which uses Intl.DateTimeFormat object. I get Intl not defined error. (acc to https://v8.dev/blog/intl we should have Intl support on v8)

ICU version installed in system is 70.1 which shows that is supports Intl object. I tried to map v8 version with Intl compatibilty but i didn't found any reference which suggest that issue is due to v8 version.

Can anybody help if its due to v8 version mismatch or perhaps how the ICU library are installed or something else

Added the link to the sample project : https://github.com/hardikjain1008/test-v8/

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77952534/referenceerror-intl-is-not-defined and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77265797/intl-not-defined-error-add-intl-support-to-v8, right? As long as the official instructions work, and you're not sharing a complete reproducible example of what exactly you're doing that's different, there isn't much anyone can do to help you.

Comment: @jmrk added the reproducible example on https://github.com/hardikjain1008/test-v8/

Answer (score 1):

Comparing your code to the [official "hello, world" sample](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/11.6/samples/hello-world.cc), a few things stand out:

- Your question says you're working with V8 8.8.278.17 (which is a surprising choice, given its old age: 3 years!), but the repro case you've uploaded uses V8 11.6.189.22 (from a more reasonable 5 months ago). Which is it?
- The official sample calls `v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);`. You do `v8::V8::InitializeICU();`. Have you tried doing what the official sample does? Does that help?
- The [documentation for `v8::V8::InitializeICU()`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/11.6/include/v8-initialization.h#135) (which you're calling) says:

  ```
  * If V8 was compiled with the ICU data in an external file, the location
  * of the data file has to be provided.
  ```

  Since you're not providing the data file's location, I guess it's not surprising that something isn't working?
- You call `PLATFORM = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform()` twice. While that's most likely unrelated to the problem you're having, it's also entirely unnecessary.

Comment: 1.Apologies yes the version being used is 8.8.278.17

2. I tried with v8::V8::InitializeICU(ICU_DATA_FILE_PATH) and v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(ICU_DATA_FILE_PATH) where ICU_DATA_FILE_PATH variable points to icudtl.dat file

Comment: @Naman: I see two paths you could pursue: (1) The official sample works. Compare every little detail you're doing differently until you find the cause of things not working. I tried that above; maybe there are more differences to be found. You could start with the sample, confirm that it works, and add your changes one by one until you find the one that breaks things. (2) Build everything (including V8) in Debug mode and step through the initialization sequence in a debugger. Something must be going wrong somewhere, and with a debugger you should be able to find it.